# Material Design : Grid with cards auto height

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material

I'm looking to have a grid with cards auto height, something like this :

[image]

I'm using Material Design and Angular 4, if there is some solutions with React or VueJS that would be good too.
I started to use the dependency flex-layout but I have always something like this :

[image]

Here is my code :

```
 <div class="row" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxFlexFill fxFlexAlign="center">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="card bg-color-white">

                <div class="card-content">
                    <p>Original Content podcast: Neqsqsdqsdqsdqsdqsdqsdqsdqsdqsdqsdqsdqsdqsddqdqsdqsdqsdqsdqsdtflix’s ‘Queer Eye’ revival feels surprisingly heartfelt  by @anthonyha and @jordanrcrook and @jshieber</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="card bg-color-white">

                <div class="card-content">
                    <p>Original Content podcast: Netflix’s ‘Queer Eye’ revival feels surprisingly heartfelt by @anthonyha and @jordanrcrook and @jshieber</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>   <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="card bg-color-white">

            <div class="card-content">
                <p>Original Content podcast: Netflix’s ‘Queer Eye’ revival feels surprisingly heartfelt by @anthonyha and @jordanrcrook and @jshieber</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="card bg-color-white">

            <div class="card-content">
                <p>Original Content podcast: Netflix’s ‘Queer Eye’ revival feels surprisingly heartfeltby @anthonyha and @jordanrcrook and @jshieber</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="card bg-color-white">

                <div class="card-content">
                    <p>Original Content podcaqfdsdglklklkdfkgldfklglkdflkgdfklgkldfgkldfklgkldfgkldfkglst: Netflix’s ‘Queer Eye’ revival feels surprisingly heartfelt  by @anthonyha and @jordanrcrook and @jshieber</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="card bg-color-white">

                <div class="card-content">
                    <p>Original Content podcast: Netflix’s ‘Queer Eye’ revival feels surprisingly heartfelt  by @anthonyha and @jordanrcrook and @jshieber</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>   <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="card bg-color-white">

            <div class="card-content">
                <p>Original Content podcast: Netflix’s ‘Queer Eye’ revival feels surprisingly heartfelt  by @anthonyha and @jordanrcrook and @jshieber</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="card bg-color-white">

                <div class="card-content">
                    <p>Original Content podcast: Netflix’qsdqsdqsd qsfdsgsfgsfhdgjgsd s sdgsfhdf s ‘Queer Eye’ revival feels surprisingly heartfelt h by @anthonyha and @jordanrcrook and @jshieber</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: With auto height you mean that each card is as big as its content?

Comment: Exactly as shown on the attache picture

Comment: for those like me that had trouble seeing what the issue is with @StrangerB. results are, I think it is that the top of the cards in the 2nd row are all even, instead of pushed against the bottom of the cards in the first row.

Comment: @StrangerB. it would be helpful if you could describe exactly the issue between the results you are getting vs what you want within the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely use material cards from the angular-material package, combined with angular flex layout (I.e. [[1]](https://alligator.io/angular/flex-layout/), [[2]](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs)) to make really flexible layout combinations.

Have a look especially at the second link I posted, which shows several examples similar to what you want to achieve.